# Stuck syphon hose

Tags: ford, e150

Over filled oil by a couple quarts, 2000 Ford E150 5.4. Used a plastic siphon hose kit to no avail now the tube is stuck in oil fill tube. Not the dipstick.

How do I remove it without breaking it in the fill tube?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Sorry for you issues ... what's keeping it in place? How is it stuck?

Comment: Looked at some pics. It may be better if you treat this different: remove the plastic fill hose tube, looks like the just untwist but not sure on this. When you have it all off you may be able to see what is hanging it up and remove safely